# Does having multiple instances of GAE SDK on your machine cause conflicts?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant, sdk, google-eclipse-plugin

I would like to install both the Google-Eclipse plugin (which I *believe* also install the GAE SDK) for my Eclipse instance, so that I may take advantage of a lot of the IDE tools and features it comes with, and also so that I can run my app from inside Eclipse.

I would also like to install just the pure GAE SDK so that I can run my app outside of Eclipse on my regular system.

Because the GAE SDK is a diverse and complex beast, I am worried about having two instances of the GAE SDK installed on the same machine (setting conflicting ENV VARs, trying to open the same port number, etc.).

Obviously, I would take care to never be running the 2 GAE dev servers (1 that ships with the Eclipse plugin, and the other that ships with the pure SDK) at the same time, but that might not guarantee that I have 0 conflicts.

I would also be fine with just installing the Eclipse plugin *if* there was a way to configure the GAE SDK that it ships with to run both from Eclipse as well as the bash shell. That would probably be the easiest but I don't believe this is possible to do.

Any thoughts as to what my options are here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by having a single SDK installed and using it for both Eclipse and also for bash shell.
You can do that by following the steps below:

1. Download a Suitable GAE SDK from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) and install it.
2. Open Eclipse and Select Help->Install new software.
3. In ***work with box*** enter the url as `http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2` and from the list of available softwares select only "***Google Plugin for Eclipse***" software and select any other required plugin but **not the** ***SDKs***. Keep it unchecked!
4. After installing the selected plugins, in Window->Preferences->Google->AppEngine click on add and then select the installation directory as the directory from step 1 and give a suitable name. Make it as default.

Now you are good to go.
If you need to run from shell, invoke `dev_appserver` from the installation directory. Or if you want to run from from eclipse just run it from there.